# converting Byte array to SecureString

Tags: c#, security, type-conversion, azure-keyvault, securestring

What is best way to create `SecureString`(unicode encoded) from `byte array`?
I want to store my decrypted DEK key in memory, the decryption process is made by Azure.KeyVault(api), that produce byte array as a result.

```
var keyBytes = client.DecryptAsync(url, keyName, keyVersion, algorithm, encryptedKeyBytes).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Result;
```

I have created something like that but I am not proud from that implementations.

```
var secureKey = new SecureString();
var secureKeyCharArray = Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(keyBytes);

for (int i = 0; i < keyBytes.Length; i++)
{
    keyBytes[i] = 0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < secureKeyCharArray.Length; i++)
{
    secureKey.AppendChar(secureKeyCharArray[i]);
    secureKeyCharArray[i] = (char)0;
}

secureKey.MakeReadOnly();
```

After rewriting DEK key to `SecureString` variable I am cleaning both array: `secureKeyCharArray` and `keyBytes` but i dont know that it is enough.

Do you know some better solutions for that case? Maybe some nuget packages? Or maybe my whole idea is wrong?

Thanks for any suggestion.

=== Edited ===============================================================

But if we focus on storing secure data in memeory, do you know any better solution than `SecureString`? Work with this type is a little bit dificult, for example to read key from that vartiable I am using something like that:

```
IntPtr unmanagedString = IntPtr.Zero;
try
{
    unmanagedString = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(securePassword);
    return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(unmanagedString);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(unmanagedString);
}
```

I dont know that it is ok for production purpose to use Marshal classes.

Comment: the code in the edit does bad things; you've just allocated a managed string with the password in it - something you want very hard to avoid: you have *no control* over the lifetime of that; *at best* you can hope that the recipient decides to use `unsafe` code to wipe the contents when they're done

Comment: So you think that I should read data from SecureString in different way? Or I misunderstand your answer.:D

Comment: it is an unfortunate feature of `SecureString` that it is virtually unusable by anything :) what I am saying is that you need to be *really* careful about the lifetime when you *do* access the content, and just returning a string doesn't make that obvious to the consumer

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious problem is:

```
.GetAwaiter().GetResult().Result;
```

You should **almost never** do that; `await` would be far preferable:

```
var keyBytes = await client.DecryptAsync(url, keyName, keyVersion,
                                         algorithm, encryptedKeyBytes);
```

Using `.GetAwaiter().GetResult().Result;` on an incomplete awaitable operation can cause hard deadlocks. More generally, you should only try to access the result if you **know** (either by checking `IsCompleted`, or because you've awaited) that it is complete.

---

As for the rest: it really depends what your aim is here; and note that *yes* `SecureString` is *more secure than `string`*, but it isn't actually secure in the strong sense - a malicious user can still reverse it. It is mostly an *inconvenience* and something that makes it hard for memory scanners to *find* the data. Other than that, what you have looks OK? Note that if you want to avoid the `AppendChar` loop you could use `fixed` in an `unsafe` block and make use of the constructor that takes a `char*` and `int`, but that's just a performance tweak. You'd still need to erase the source array manually, of course. If you're going that route, and the password isn't large, you could actually `stackalloc` a block to decode into, rather than having `secureKeyCharArray` as an array. You would still need to manually wipe the `stackalloc` area when you're done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, This solutions is still in POC I will implement your advice after I will resolve all secure issues :). I have edited my question for replay on your answer, please check this out.